# JODATIME vs System.currentTimeMillis() in terms of accuracy

Tags: java, android, jodatime

I need to get the most accurate time (which is synced with the system clock), in millis. 
I know `System.currentTimeMillis()` is accurate. 
I also know `JodaTime`'s millis is accurate.

Which is more accurate?

Thanks!

Comment: This is `System.currentTimeMillis()`. As it is what Joda Time probably uses anyway, there is no difference at all, I believe.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Joda Time just piggy backs on `System.currentTimeMillis` by default. Everything in Joda Time uses [`DateTimeUtils.currentTimeMillis`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTimeUtils.html#currentTimeMillis%28%29), which defaults to using `System.currentTimeMillis()` but which can be replaced using [`setCurrentMillisProvider()`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTimeUtils.html#setCurrentMillisProvider%28org.joda.time.DateTimeUtils.MillisProvider%29).

If you want it to be synced with the system clock, `System.currentTimeMillis` should be fine. You may be able to get a more accurate time using an NTP provider, of course.

(Personally I dislike the static dependency Joda exposes - it's better than not being able to do anything for tests, but it's still global state. I prefer to pass a `Clock` object in as a dependency to anything which needs the current time of day.)

Answer (score 2):

[System.nanoTime()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime%28%29) is more accurate than [System.currentTimeMillis()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis%28%29).

This is what the documentation for Joda Time's [DateTimeUtils#currentTimeMillis()](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTimeUtils.html#currentTimeMillis%28%29) says:

> By default this returns `System.currentTimeMillis().` This may be changed using other methods in this class.

You can use [DateTimeUtils#setCurrentMillisProvider](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTimeUtils.html#setCurrentMillisProvider%28org.joda.time.DateTimeUtils.MillisProvider%29) , *to change the behavior of `currentTimeMillis()`*.

Comment: It's *different*. The two are never really alternatives to each other. `nanoTime` is used to measure the difference between two times accurately but shouldn't be used for "what is the current time". `System.currentTimeMillis` is the reverse.